# Delete word around cursor and move to insert mode

Tags: cut-copy-paste

## My Problem

### Going from:

[image]

### To:

[image]

I'm doing some editing (interactive rebase on a git repo, but the problem is generally relevant).

1. The cursor is on a word (`pick`), and I would like to delete it , regardless of the cursor position in it
2. Then, take the cursor back to the position of its first characterand
3. Immediately insert the new word (`r`)

## My Question

Is there a shortcut to the common sequence of: Delete word, go to its beginning, move to insert mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
ciw
```

The mnemonic is **c**hange **i**nside **w**ord.

The `c` command is like the `d` command, except that it immediately goes to insert mode afterwards. So this is really like using `diwi`. Using `iw` instead of `w` is to make sure the whole word your cursor is on gets deleted, not just the rest of the word from where your cursor is.

Comment: Thanks! <More characters>